# objects not being passed to function in flask route

Tags: python, function, flask, decorator, routes

I have a function and a flask route setup. However, when I go to "simplepage", I get an error "NameError: global name 'aaa' is not defined". Why aren't any of the objects being passed to testfun? Is this something due to the app.route decorator, or due to flask? Can I make all the objects passed to testfun? My actual code is way more complicated with many more objects that would need to be passed, but this simplified scenario was created to illustrate my issue.

```
def testfun():
    b=aaa

@app.route("/simplepage/", methods=['GET'])
def simplepage():
    aaa=1
    testfun()
    return flask.render_template('page.html')
```

Comment: Why not pass `aaa` as an argument to `testfun()` (i.e. `testfun(aaa)`)

Comment: well, in my real application there are a lot more objects to pass and i would also have to re-import a lot of modules too, and do this for multiple functions. i'd prefer to avoid all that and make the code cleaner and simpler to maintain. i don't think i normally have this problem.

Comment: After a little research I'm fairly sure this is a [scoping](http://stackoverflow.com/a/292502/322909) issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what is happening is this

```
def t():
    print aaa 

def s():
    aaa = "hi"
    t()

s()
```

Python looks for `aaa` first in the local scope, then in any wrapping function scopes, then globally, and lastly in the builtins. Since the `s` functions scope isn't any of those things python throws an undefined error because it can't find `aaa`.

One solution would be to declare `aaa` as global.

```
def t():
    print aaa

def s():
    global aaa
    aaa = "hi"
    t()

s()
```

Comment: I guess the confusion is that an object has to be defined where the most top level function is called or defined, but any sub functions only get objects passed to them from the level where they have been defined and not where they are called.

Comment: def s():
        
        def t():
        
            print aaa
        
        aaa = "hi"
        
        t()
        
    s()

Answer (score 3):

This is due to [Python's scoping rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/292502/322909) (as @johnthexiii pointed out) - `testfun->aaa` is bound to the global scope because there is no variable named `aaa` declared anywhere inside of `testfun` and there is no enclosing scope (i. e. `testfun` is not declared inside another function or class).

You'll want to pass `aaa` as an argument to `testfun`:

```
testfun(aaa)
```

If `testfun` requires too many params there are several ways you can DRY up the code:

- **Use multiple functions:** If `testfun` is doing a lot of work then break it up into multiple functions that return intermediate transformations of the data:

  ```
  def start_test(arg1, arg2, arg3):
      # do stuff with args
      return result_stage_1

  def continue_test(arg3, arg4, arg5):
      # do stuff with args
      return result_stage_2

  def finalize_test(arg7, arg8):
      # do stuff with args
      return real_result
  ```
- **Use keyword arguments:** If a variable number of arguments are needed and `testfun` *cannot* be broken up you can use keyword arguments to simplify the calling of the function:

  ```
  def testfun(arg1=None, arg2=None, arg3=None, arg4=None,
                arg5=None, arg6=None, arg7=None, arg8=None):
      # do stuff with args

  # call it as so
  args = {"arg1": "some args", "arg5": "have defaults"}
  if complex_condition:
      args["arg3"] = 17
  elif another_condition:
      args["arg7"] = 10

  testfun(**args)
  ```
- **Encapsulate state and behavior with classes (or closures):** If neither of the above will work for you then you probably need to leave the realm of stateless functions and create classes or closure-creating functions to preserve your state and enable you to modify behavior as needed.